# Highcharts:How to show Bubble randomly

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

How i can arrange bubble randomly without overlap

```
var Highcharts2 = $('#attBubbleGraph').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'bubble',
          plotBorderWidth: 1,
          margin: [1, 1, 1, 1]
        },

        title: {
          text: 'Testing'
        },



        series: [

          {
          showInLegend: false,  
          name: 'Present', 
          data: [
            [0, 0, 50],
            [2, 0, 50],
            [4, 0, 50],
          ],

        }]

      });
```

in the above code used x,y and radius (value) like below

```
data: [
                [0, 0, 50],
                [2, 0, 50],
                [4, 0, 50],
              ],
```

But I'am Looking for a bubble graph of radius (value) with random x, y without overlapping

Comment: What is the desired result? Some restrictions are needed because you can generate (theoretically) an infinite number of bubbles that do not overlap on the given area (for example 200 x 200px). How many bubbles should appear?

Comment: Number of bubble is dynamic, depends on database data, actually i want bubble with radius proportional to it value, random location in the graph without overlapping

Comment: Highcharts doesn't provide any mechanism for detecting overlapping bubbles. You can create your own algorithm for this (this article seems to be a good staring point: http://www.inkfood.com/collision-detection-with-svg/). This demo shows how to access SVG's of all points: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xvnke874/ Collision detection can be performed in `chart.events.load`. There you can update the overlapping points with new random positions and check if they overlap again.

Comment: Thanks for your  replay, i am looking for any highchart settings to do so.